# Why is Around omitted when the uncertainty is zero?

Tags: numerical-value, around, head

I have a list of values with errors and I use `Around[x, dx]`. Some of those values have an error of zero though. *Mathematica* removes the [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) [`Head`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) for those values which leaves me with a list of a mix of objects. This becomes a problem when I want to address the `Around` head specifically with `Around[x, dx]["Value"]`.

Here is a small example of what my code looks like.

```
test = {Around[0, 0], Around[0, 0], Around[0, 0], Around[0, 0], Around[0, 0], Around[3, 0.1], Around[3, 0.1], Around[3, 0.1], Around[0, 0], Around[0, 0], Around[0, 0]}
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Around[3., 0.1], Around[3., 0.1], Around[3., 0.1], 0, 0, 0} *)

Head[#] & /@ test
(* {Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Around, Around, Around, Integer, Integer, nteger} *)

#["Value"] & /@ test
(* {0["Value"], 0["Value"], 0["Value"], 0["Value"], 0["Value"], 3., 3., 3., 0["Value"], 0["Value"], 0["Value"]} *)
```

**Is there a way of keeping the Around Head for zero uncertainty or do I have to do some workaround?**

Comment: You may specify an uncertainty of  $MachineEpsilon: `Around[1, $MachineEpsilon]`

Comment: This would be an acceptable workaround. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: As an alternative to `$MachineEpsilon` one can go even more extreme and use `$MinMachineNumber` while still staying with machine-precision numbers (I guess)... but if one really needs to deal with hair-splitting semantics, @rhermans answer is probably somewhat more applicable.

Comment: Better `Around[x_,0|0.]:=Around[x,N@Power[10,-Precision[x]]]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### My `ReplaceAll` solution

Probably you can act only over the elements that have the [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) [`Head`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) using [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (a.k.a `/.`) with a suitable [rule](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Rules.html) with [`Blank`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)`[Around]` (a.k.a. `_Around`) that stands for any expression with a head `Around`.

```
ReplaceAll[
    test
    , x_Around :> x["Value"]
]
(* {0,0,0,0,0,3.,3.,3.,0,0,0} *)
```

### @DanielHuber's comment

Or after the excellent comment by @DanielHuber, in more detail,

```
Unprotect[Around];
Around[x_,0|0.]:=Around[x,$MachineEpsilon]
Protect[Around];
```

Now your code gives

```
test = {Around[0, 0], Around[0, 0], Around[0, 0], Around[0, 0], Around[0, 0], Around[3, 0.1], Around[3, 0.1], Around[3, 0.1], Around[0, 0], Around[0, 0], Around[0, 0]}
```

[image]

```
Head[#] & /@ test
(* Around,Around,Around,Around,Around,Around,Around,Around,Around,Around,Around} *)

#["Value"] & /@ test
(* {0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,3.,3.,3.,0.,0.,0.} *)
```

### Improving after that

Probably also better to use the [`Precision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) of the actual number as given.

```
Unprotect[Around];
Around[x_,0|0.]:=Around[x,N@Power[10,-Precision[x]]]
Protect[Around];
```

Comment: This is way more elegant than what I did. I converted everything to strings and removed the "["Value"]" part. Thanks for the suggestion